# relation between size of matrix and condition number

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, inverse

I have a matrix A of size NxM. Is there any relationship between size of a matrix A with the condition number ? I am computing the pseudo inverse (`pinv` in matlab ) for A. I understand that the pseudo inverse of A is only possible when rank(A) is greater than equal to M. But, I want to know if there is anyway to reason about the condition number `cond(A)` with that of NxM. In other words, how is the condition number related to the rank of the matrix?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that the pseudo inverse of A is only possible when rank(A) is greater than equal to M.

This is incorrect. The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is defined for all matrices, and  Matlab's  `pinv` implements it for all matrices. The `pinv` [command description](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html) has an example of this sort. It's true that the computation may be less expensive for matrices of full rank, but this is a different issue (and in any case, it seems that Matlab goes through SVD regardless of the rank).

> Is there any relationship between size of a matrix A with the condition number ?

No. The identity matrix has condition number $1$, regardless of its size. On the other hand, 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 10^{-9}\end{pmatrix}$$
is a $2 \times 2$ matrix of rank $2$, yet it has `cond(A)` of about $10^9$.